# Random movide clip without loop?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I created some `MovieClips` and put all of them on the stage.  I'm trying to move a random `MovieClip`, using it only once, but at the same time I need to know which one it is because it will conflict with other tween effects.  Is there an easy way to do that?

Here is what I've tried:

```
var biryukseklev1, ikiyukseklev1, ucyukseklev1, dortyukseklev1, besyukseklev1:int;
var assignavalue1, assignavalue2:int;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,survivordondurlev6);
function survivordondurlev6(e:Event) {
    if (biryerlessurlev1 == 0) {
        biryukseklev1  = 764;//36
    } else if (biryerlessurlev1 == 1) {
        biryukseklev1 = 680;//120
    } else if (biryerlessurlev1 == 2) {
        biryukseklev1 = 596;//204
    } else if (biryerlessurlev1 == 3) {
        biryukseklev1 = 512;//288
    } else if (biryerlessurlev1 == 4) {
        biryukseklev1 = 428;//372
    }

    if (assignavalue1 == 0 && rabbitstatus.text.length < 2) { //Make sure to not used before
        var my:Tween = new Tween(rabbit, "y", Back.easeInOut, rabbit.y, rabbit.y -biryukseklev1, 3, true);
        rabbitstatus.text = "okfull";
    } else if((assignavalue1 == 1 && birdstatus.text.length < 2){ //Make sure to not used before
        var mys:Tween = new Tween(bird, "y", Back.easeInOut, bird.y, bird.y -biryukseklev1, 3, true);
        birdstatus.text = "okfull";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: 1-First assign a 5 random movie clip.(30 Movie clips already on stage)
2-Set the Y for tween (biryerlessurlev1)
3-I use for this code for making sure to not used before to movie clip. ( birdstatus.text.length<2)
4-Tween effect movie clips.

How I set ( var mys:Tween = new Tween(RANDOMovieClip) ? And Is there an easy way to check used / assigned before ?

Comment: So, you have a pool of 30 movieClips.  You want to randomly animate 5 of them,  wait for something?, then animate more of them (but not the same ones as before)?

Comment: Yes only 5 of them then event listener could remove.

Comment: Animate for only 5 movie clip and only once.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of which clips you've animated, then you'll have to have some way of iterating through them.  The easiest list would be an `Array`, though how you mark them as "animated" is up to you.  If you never plan on animating them again, then simply removing the ones that you've animated, and leaving the rest for later will work.

Below is example code, which you should be able to run in a new scene.  You should be able to apply it to your needs with some small edits.

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

// We'll keep track of which blocks still need to be animated by including them in this list
// Once we animate a block, we remove it from the list.
var pool:Array = [];

// Populate the stage with blocks.
for (var i:int = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    var block:Sprite = createBlock();
    addChild(block);    
    block.y = 50;
    if (i > 0) { block.x = block.width * i; }
    pool.push(block);
}

// Create an interactive button.
var txt:TextField = new TextField();
txt.text = "Do something";
addChild(txt);
txt.addEventListener("click", animateNext);

function createBlock():Sprite {
    // Creates a single, randomly colored block.
    var block:Sprite = new Sprite();
    block.graphics.beginFill(random(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF));
    block.graphics.drawRect(0,0,16,16);
    block.graphics.endFill();
    return block;
}

function random(low:Number, high:Number):Number {
    // Returns a random number between the low and high numbers.
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1+high-low)) + low;
}

function animateNext(e:Event):void {
    // Do this 5 times.
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        // As long as we have blocks in the pool...
        if (pool.length > 0) {
            // Pick a random block from the pool
            var index:int = random(0, pool.length-1);

            // Animate it
            new Tween(pool[index], "y", Back.easeInOut, pool[index].y, pool[index].y + 50, 3, true);

            // Remove it from the pool so it isn't picked again
            pool.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise, break the loop.
            break;
        }
    }
}
```